# How to execute function inside array of objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

mentioned below:

```
users = [
    {
        name: 'Test User',
        onSelected: function (par1, par2) {
            // some operation with par1, par2
            alert('Test User');
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Test User 2',
        onSelected: function (par1, par2, par3) {
            // some operation with par1, par2, par3
            alert('Test User 2');
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Test User 3',
        onSelected: () => {
            this.router.navigate(['/some/path', 12])
                    .then();
        }
    }
];
```

I pass this array to my child component with the help of inputs decorator, as shown below,
**app.component.html:**

```
<render-users [users]='users' (selectedUser)="selectedUserManager($event)"></render-users>
```

Now Am able to emit the selected user using `Output` and `Event Emitter`, as shown below,

**render-users.component.html:**

```
<div 
 *ngFor="let user of users" 
 (click)="setSelectedUser(user)">
</div>
```

**render.component.ts:**

```
setSelectedUser(user: User): void {
 this.selectedUser.emit(user);
}
```

My question is how do I execute a function inside the selected Object? Here, I can call `$event.onSelected()` in app.compoent.ts file as show below,

**app.component.ts:**

```
selectedUserManager($event) {
    $event.onSelected()
}
```

But in the case of a different function parameter, how do manage without switch case inside app.component.ts

In NgFor Loop whenever I select any particular user, the function attached to **onSelected Key** should be executed.

Here I can't use a switch case mechanism, instead, I have to execute the function of that selected user.

*In a more specific word is there any way I can get a callback within the same array object?*

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pa7iyw)**

If I have left put out any extra details please let me know and thanks in advance.

Comment: In what kind of situation you want to execute it?

Comment: Hi @Mulperi I have updated the question.,

Comment: Did you try user.onSelected(); ?

Comment: I think you need to use it this way

``<div 
 *ngFor="let user of users" 
 (click)="user. onSelected">
</div>``.

It is a function on user object which you will get on iteration. You don't seems to be calling that at all.

Comment: @Mulperi, Yes, I tried and It works(shows alert). But in the case of a different function parameter, how do manage without switch case inside app.component.ts?

Comment: @SandipNirmal, what about parameters how to I pass them in your suggestion?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: @Shasha. This way. ``<div *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="user. onSelected(user)"> </div>``

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SandipNirmal , I understood your point and this way I can execute the function. But how I can manage parameters, I have updated the question with different use cases.
Also, what is the point of passing the user object again as a parameter, coz i have already passed parameters while array initialization!

Comment: Also, I have Stackblitz Demo.

Answer (score 0):

forked your stackbliz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-memv6o?file=src%2Findex.html

Passed three parameters and all are not required in function defination